# Filtering to outliers according to a grouping and with a special condition

Tags: r, outliers

I have time series data where each Country/Animal grouping has 30 years (one result each year).

I'm hoping to identify outliers that are 100x the mean of that group (i.e. each 30 block of Country/Animal).

I've run this code;

```r
outliers <- long %>%
  group_by(Country, Species) %>%
  mutate(is_outlier = abs(Capture) >= 100 * mean(Capture))
```

However it appears to only identify zero values, which it shouldn't be doing if the code is correct (no outlier should be zero).

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Here is some sample data;

| Country | Species | Year | Capture |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Japan | OWS | 1993 | 480 |
| Japan | OWS | 1994 | 2 |
| Japan | OWS | 1995 | 690 |
| Japan | OWS | 1996 | 0 |
| Japan | OWS | 1997 | 0 |
| Japan | OWS | 1998 | 0 |
| Japan | OWS | 1999 | 65 |
| Japan | OWS | 2000 | 2344 |
| Japan | OWS | 2001 | 46 |
| Japan | OWS | 2002 | 546 |
| Japan | OWS | 2003 | 23 |
| Japan | OWS | 2004 | 234 |
| Japan | OWS | 2005 | 0 |
| Japan | OWS | 2006 | 23 |
| Japan | OWS | 2007 | 546 |
| Japan | OWS | 2008 | 13 |

Comment: Please provide sample data, perhaps the data from one country/animal pair.

Comment: You're taking the mean of `Capture` *including* the outlier and multiplying it by 100.  The mean only grows bigger with the outliers included, and especially with only positive values as in your example data, it is not likely that any values of `Capture` will be greater than `mean(Capture) * 100`. If you're looking to detect outliers, I would suggest looking into using IQR instead

Comment: I would second what nightstand said, but also question why you are removing so-called outliers. How do you know they don't contain useful information?

Comment: this is quite good https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/561942

Comment: Hi Mark - not removing them, focusing on them for further investigation. Thanks all - will proceed with IQR instead (can get that code working)

Comment: Filtering Out Zero Values Before Calculating the Mean: This will ensure that the mean calculation is not skewed by zero values.

Ensure that Outliers are Not Zero: Modify the is_outlier calculation to exclude zero values    library(dplyr)

outliers <- long %>%
  group_by(Country, Species) %>%
  mutate(mean_capture = mean(Capture[Capture != 0], na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(is_outlier = (abs(Capture) >= 100 * mean_capture) & Capture != 0)

# Optional: filter to only include outliers
outliers_only <- filter(outliers, is_outlier)